# Laravel eloquent: How does relation inherit functions from query builder?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

how do they achieve, that `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation` has access to all query builder functions?

[image]

I see they have a $query property, but does not explain how all its methods are available inside relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are aware of php [magic methods](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) then you will know [__call method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call)
this method will be called when you initialize a php object and you try to call a method which is not available in the class. By using **__call method** from the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation` class they are forwarding the call to `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`. I will explain it very clearly by pointing out the code.

Inside the laravel framework there is a trait named as [ForwardsCalls](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php) . This trait is used in many classes to handle the call forwarding to another class.

So here is how the call from the `Relation` class is forwarded to `Builder` class. While initilting the new Relation class **Builder** class will be [initialized](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Relation.php#L81). So when you try to call a method from reltion class which is not available it will call [__call](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Relation.php#L475) method. After that it will look for a [available macros](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Relation.php#L477) . So when a macros method is not found. Then it will use [forwardDecoratedCallTo from ForwardsCalls](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php#L50) Trait.

So **forwardDecoratedCallTo** will accept 3 arguments namely `$object, $method and $parameters`. Whereas

1. `$object` will be `$this->query` which has a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` instance.
2. `$method` will be the method the you try to access from Builder Method.
3. `$parameters` will be the all the parameters that is be passed to the method.

I will try to Demonstrate will the example without the traits and helpers from laravel

```
class ClassTwo {
  
public function classTwoMethodOne()
    {
      dd(__FUNCTION__.' has been called');
    }  
  
  public function classTwoMethodTwo()
    {
      dd(__FUNCTION__.' has been called');
    }  

  public function classTwoMethodThree()
    {
    //you cannot call this method dynamically 
      dd(__FUNCTION__.' has been called');
    }  

}


class ClassOne {
  
public function classOneMethodOne()
    {
      dd(__FUNCTION__.' has been called');
    }  
  
  public function classOneMethodTwo()
    {
      dd(__FUNCTION__.' has been called');
    }  

  public function __call($methodName, $arguments)
    {
    
    $methodsTobeForwarededtoClassTwo = [
        'classTwoMethodOne',
        'classTwoMethodTwo',
      // 'classTwoMethodThree' 
      //i have commented this method so you cannot access it 
      //from dynamic calls
    ];
    if(in_array($methodName,$methodsTobeForwarededtoClassTwo))
    {
      return (new ClassTwo)->{$methodName}($arguments);
    }
             dd(sprintf(
            'Call to undefined method ClassTwo::%s()',  $methodName
        ));
    }
}
```

So here comes the testing part.

```
$classOneobj = new ClassOne;
```

> Basic Test

1. `dump($classOneobj->classOneMethodOne());` will output as **classOneMethodOne has been called**
2. `dump($classOneobj->classOneMethodTwo());` will output as **classOneMethodTwo has been called**

> Dynamic Call Test

1. `dump($classOneobj->classTwoMethodOne());` will output as **classTwoMethodOne has been called**
2. `dump($classOneobj->classTwoMethodTwo());` will output as **classOneMethodTwo has been called**
3. `dump($classOneobj->classTwoMethodThree());` will output as **Call to undefined method ClassTwo::classTwoMethodThree()** Because i have commented that method in `__call` function in `ClassOne`.

If you still need clarity please post a comment